What allowable date forms can be used in pandas bdate_series holidays?
I am currently testing the bdate_series to use in my code.
The following code still outputs July 2 as a date, even though I expected it to be excluded.
>>> pd.bdate_range(start='20240701', end='20240705',holidays=["20240702"],freq="C")

DatetimeIndex(['2024-07-01', '2024-07-02', '2024-07-03', '2024-07-04', '2024-07-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')

The following modification corrects this, but I don't understand why:
>>> pd.bdate_range(start='20240701', end='20240705',holidays=["2024-07-02"],freq="C")

DatetimeIndex(['2024-07-01', '2024-07-03', '2024-07-04', '2024-07-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')

I assume this is because some parts of the function allow more flexibility in specifying datetime arguments than others.  Can someone explain?
I am using
pandas                : 2.2.1
numpy                 : 1.26.4

As far as I can tell, start and end are Timestamps, while holidays gets converted into a Frequency. Read through the Pandas source code if you're curious.

chk pandas bdate_range document holidays : Dates to exclude from the set of valid business days, passed to numpy.busdaycalendar, only used when custom frequency strings are passed.

holidays of numpy.busdaycalendar need list of yyyy-mm-yy form
